# indexOf começando pela direita

Tags: javascript

### Problema

Gostaria que quando eu fizesse `"asdhusaidhi asdhasuidhu".indexOf('s')` ele me retornasse `17` referente ao ultimo **s** da string, por exemplo, ele começar a procurar pela direita..

mas ao invés disso, ele me retornou `1` referente ao primeiro **s** encontrado

### Pergunta?

Como posso fazer ele começar a procurar pela direita?

Comment: testa .lastIndexOf()

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Podes usar [.lastIndexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf) que retorna o ultimo index onde essa *string* `'s'` foi encontrada.

```
"asdhusaidhi asdhasuidhu".lastIndexOf('s'); // 17
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/d0jbb6x7/

Answer (score 8):

A função que você deseja é a [`lastIndexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf)

```js
console.log("asdhusaidhi asdhasuidhu".lastIndexOf('s'));
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/String/IndexOf.js).